# Disabling Javascript And WebRTC In PyQt5

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, pyqt5

Does anyone know how to disable Javascript and WebRTC in PyQtWebEngine? I want to have a privacy centered Web Browser that I made so that's why I want to know this. Please tell me if you know the modules and the parts of code that I'll need to add to my PyQt5 Application to disable Javascript and WebRTC (By the way this is only a snippet of the program).

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngine
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineSettings
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
from functools import cached_property
import os
import sys

#Main window.
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    #Constructor.
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://searx.xyz"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("Thing.png"))
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
        self.showMaximized()

        #Setting the user agent of the browser.
        chrome = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.7113.93 Safari/537.36"
        edge = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4482.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/92.0.874.0"
        firefox = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
        brave = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.38 Safari/537.36 Brave/75"
        safari = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_3) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1 Safari/605.1.15"
        chromium = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; GNU/Linux) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chromium/88.0.4324.150 Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36 Tesla/DEV-BUILD-4d1a3f465b3a"

        user_agent_string = chrome

        self.browser.page().profile().setHttpUserAgent(
            user_agent_string
        )

        #Creating a tab widget.
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()

        #Making the tabs movable.
        self.tabs.setMovable(True)
 
        #Making document mode true.
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
 
        #Adding action when tab is changed.
        self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.current_tab_changed)
 
        #Making tabs closeable.
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
 
        #Adding action when tab close is requested.
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_current_tab)
 
        #Making tabs as central widget.
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
 
        #Creating a tool bar for navigation.
        navtb = QToolBar("Navigation")
        #Making it not movable.
        navtb.setMovable(False)
        #Making it so you can not delete it.
        navtb.setFloatable(False)
 
        #Adding tool bar tot he main window.
        self.addToolBar(navtb)
 
        #Creating back action.
        back_btn = QAction("Go Back To Previous Page", self)
        back_btn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("BackArrow.png"))
        #Adding action to back button.
        #Making current tab go back.
        back_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().back())
        #Adding this to the navigation tool bar.
        navtb.addAction(back_btn)
 
        #Similarly adding forward button.
        next_btn = QAction("Go Forward To Next Page", self)
        next_btn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("ForwardArrow.png"))
        next_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().forward())
        navtb.addAction(next_btn)
 
        #Similarly adding reload button.
        reload_btn = QAction("Refresh The Page", self)
        reload_btn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("RefreshPage.png"))
        reload_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().reload())
        navtb.addAction(reload_btn)
 
        #Creating home action.
        home_btn = QAction("Go To The Home Page", self)
        home_btn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("HomePage.png"))
 
        #Adding action to home button.
        home_btn.triggered.connect(self.navigate_home)
        navtb.addAction(home_btn)

        #Adding another separator.
        navtb.addSeparator()

        #Adding a separator.
        navtb.addSeparator()

        #Similarly adding add new tab action.
        add_tab_btn = QAction("Add New Tab", self)
        add_tab_btn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("AddTab.png"))
        add_tab_btn.triggered.connect(self.add_new_tab)
        navtb.addAction(add_tab_btn)
        
        #Adding another separator.
        navtb.addSeparator()

        #Adding another separator.
        navtb.addSeparator()

        #Similarly adding lock and unlock https and http action.
        self.ssl_icon = QLabel("SSL Check")
        #self.ssl_icon.setPixmap(QPixmap(os.path.join("images", "Locked.png")))
        self.ssl_icon.setPixmap(QPixmap("Locked.png"))
        navtb.addWidget(self.ssl_icon)

        #Creating a line edit widget for URL.
        self.urlbar = QLineEdit()
 
        #Adding action to line edit when enter key is pressed.
        self.urlbar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
 
        #Adding line edit to tool bar.
        navtb.addWidget(self.urlbar)

        #Similarly adding stop action.
        stop_btn = QAction("Stop Loading The Current Page", self)
        stop_btn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("StopPage.png"))
        stop_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().stop())
        navtb.addAction(stop_btn)

        #Creating first tab.
        self.add_new_tab(QUrl("https://searx.xyz"), "Homepage")
 
        #Showing all the components.
        self.show()
 
        #Setting window title.
        self.setWindowTitle("")
```

Comment: Please trim down your code to a [mre], as most of it is completely unnecessary and off topic to the question. Also, see [QWebEngineSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html) and be aware that disabling javascript will probably result in making almost any website completely unusable.

Comment: Okay, I made the code shorter so it is more of a snippet then a program.  Also, I know that disabling JS will probably break many websites and disabling WebRTC will probably will stop web apps like Discord and Google Meet from working, the reason I am doing this is because I want to make a privacy focused web browser, and disabling JS will help me accomplish that.

Comment: Also, I have tried looking at the Documentation but it is quite vague and hard to use (also the majority of the useful parts are in C++).  Anyways, do you think you can help me (I understand if you can't).

Comment: I'm not talking about complex apps, I'm referring about even normal usage. For instance, you couldn't login to almost any website, nor interact with cookie consents that would otherwise completely block the page unless accepted or rejected, and many websites won't be even able to load their content at all: Youtube won't load *anything*, not even the home page. In modern day browsing, disabling JavaScript doesn't increase the privacy, it just prevents browsing at all. That said, there's really nothing complex there: use [`setAttribute()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html#setAttribute).

Comment: PyQt is just a binding, 99.9% of classes and functions have the same names, arguments, behavior and return values of their C++ counterpart, so that documentation is valid for Python too.

Comment: Wait so what's the Attribute though is it ```setAttribute("enableJavascript", False)``` or is it something else?

Comment: Oh I see, I was under the impression that disabling Javascript would disable any malicious scripts from running, that you for informing me then in that case, even so I would still like to know.

Comment: Yes, it will disable malicious scripts, but a lot of things along with them. You can try it for yourself: open a new window in private mode, then open the consolle (usually, F12) and in the settings menu you'll be able to disable javascripts. Then start browsing and see the results. In any case, `setAttribute()` requires an *enum* as argument, not a string. See the documentation linked above, in your case it would be `settings.setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptEnabled, False)`.

Comment: It says settings is not defined, but I have `from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineSettings` imported.  I put this in my Main Window class in the __init__ function within that class.  So, do I just define it as QWebEngineSettings?  Also, when it comes to disabling others things to; I understand this but I have found many also fully HTML Websites which are quite useful.

Comment: You really need to study the documentation of the classes and functions you're using. The `settings` written above implied a reference to the `QWebEngineSettings` object returned by calling `settings()` of the [view](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#settings) or its [page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#settings).

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I need a lot more practice in PyQt5!  Okay, I actually got it to run now, so I used the basis code for switching your user agent `self.browser.page().settings.setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptEnabled, False)` although it say that there is no setAttribute, weird.  Maybe I just should remove the `page()` part of it.

Comment: You missed the parentheses of `settings()`.

Comment: Oh, thank you for telling me, but it still doesn't work; now it's not like there are any errors, not at all; it's just that you can still load up Google, YouTube and everything else with no issue, this is quite odd.  In fact I have done all of these (it doesn't fit in the comment) but none of them work, why is this:  https://pastebin.com/141qUSke

Comment: Anyways, I got it to work now; thank you for trying to help!  :)

Comment: Good, then you should post your own answer with the relative "Answer your question" button, explaining what you did and providing a [mre].